# What is the difference between web.config timeout and IIS timeout?

Tags: .net, asp.net, iis, web-config, windows-server-2008

What is the difference between the following entry in web.config:

```
 <sessionState timeout="30"/>
```

And this setting in IIS 7.5 (Default web site > Advanced Settings > Connection Limits) :

[image]

I know that the web.config is supposed to apply to the time that the ASP.NET session is kept alive, but what is the IIS setting for?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The *connection* timeout is how long a connection from a browser to the server should take till it times out. So, when the browser requests a page/image/resource, how long should IIS wait till it terminates the connection. It is stated in *seconds*.

It can also be set in the `web.config` (example is for 2 minutes, 120 seconds):

```
<limits connectionTimeout="00:02:00" />
```

The *session* timeout is how long the *session* can live. This is across multiple connections and is stated in *minutes*.

They are two different settings that control different things.

Comment: OK, so they are unrelated, that's really what I wanted to know, thanks.

Comment: so, where to put above line of code in config file. Web.config file is a big file where shall I add this piece of code and under which tag?

Comment: @Unbreakable - https://www.iis.net/configreference/system.applicationhost/sites/site/limits

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, usually, this `limits` element can be used only in applicationHost.config, directly in the sites's definition. Overrides are forbidden by default. `<section name="sites" allowDefinition="AppHostOnly" overrideModeDefault="Deny" />`

Answer (score 0):

I think IIS is the default and if you want to override them, you use web.config:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754617%28WS.10%29.aspx

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web.config