# How to Stop code executing - VB.NET Web

Tags: .net, vb.net

I'm working on a function that takes longer than 2~3 hours to finish, but i found some errors in the code and i want to stop the execution of the one that is already running.

Anyway to stop this?

I already updated the bin folder with the new version publish, but the old one keeps executing. (i know cause it sends me a keepalive email every 20mins).

**Obs.:** i tried to kill the dllhost.exe process but my user don't have permission (this is in production).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try restarting the application in IIS or just the application pool.
If that doesn't work, you might be stuck at restarting IIS.
You might want to think of [putting a timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6922603/130611). If it's connecting to a database, you can try to kill the database session, this will cause a .net error.

Comment: yes, i was thinking about to do a error in database, but the method get any error, send me and email, and keep running the other registers, hehe.

Comment: in the new version, i've already implemented a table in database to control the method, so i can stop it by deleting the register in database. But the old code that is running don't have it yet.

Comment: yep, but the erros i want to correct, is logic error... But anyway, the code has finished already, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can restart IIS which should free up the dll.  Of course, that will restart all the other sites hosted on that server.  Not sure if there is another way to free up a dll.